# how do i display the sum of a SQL query in HTML?

Tags: sql, razor, sum

I tried to do this:

```
SELECT SUM(SUBTOTAL as TODAYSALES) FROM dbo.SALESORD_HDR where ORDERDATE >=41187
```

But the browser throws an exception about the sum function saying 'SUM' is not a recognized built-in function name.

Any ideas?

Comment: if you are using something like PHP, this SQL should run on the server and never hit the front end HTML.  and yes, it should be "SUM(SUBTOTAL) as TODAYSALES"

Comment: OK, sorry. I am using MS WebMatrix, CSHTML page with Razor syntax.

Comment: @DanGrossman - why the downvote? this was sucessfully answered by forum members as an error in syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your syntax seems off. It should be `SELECT SUM(SUBTOTAL) AS TODAYSALES FROM dbo.SALESORD_HDR where ORDERDATE >= 41187`

Comment: System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection`1[System.Object] is the result now.

Answer (score 5):

Doing a

SELECT SUM(SUBTOTAL) as TODAYSALES FROM ...

would work a lot better.

Answer (score 1):

Aliases must be defined outside the expression they are targeting:

```
SELECT SUM(SUBTOTAL) as TODAYSALES FROM dbo.SALESORD_HDR where ORDERDATE >=41187
```

Comment: sorry, yes i realise that now. the result is System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection`1[System.Object]